# Render multiple svg in d3js

Tags: d3.js

Im trying to render circles in d3js. On multiply svg:s. In my HTML i have all the svg:s likte this.

```
        <section id="a" class="render">
            <svg></svg>
        </section>
        <section id="b" class="render">
            <svg></svg>
        </section>
        <section id="c" class="renderr">
            <svg></svg>
        </section>
        <section id="d" class="render">
            <svg></svg>
        </section>
```

What im trying to do is this. Depending on some values i get back from a json-call i want to render and animate the circles in different svgs.

My javascript looks like this.

```
    for(i = 0; i<json.answers[0].length; i++) {

        personal.color = json.answers[0][i].color;
        personal.answer = json.answers[0][i].alternative_id;

        if(json.answers[0][i].alternative_id == 1) {
            drawSvg("#a")
        }
        if(json.answers[0][i].alternative_id == 2) {
            drawSvg("#b")
        } 
        if(json.answers[0][i].alternative_id == 3) {
            drawSvg("#c")
        } 
        if(json.answers[0][i].alternative_id == 4) {
            drawSvg("#d")
        } 
        createCircle(personal);
    }

drawSvg = function(el) {
    svg = d3.select(el+ " svg")
    .attr("width", svgWidth)
    .attr("height", svgHeight)

    force.on("tick", function(e) {
        svg.selectAll("path")
            .attr("transform", function(d) { 
                return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; 
            }
        );
    });
}

createCircle = function(p) {
    people.push({
        type: "circle",
        size: Math.random() * 1200 + 700
    });

    force.start();

    svg.selectAll("path")
    .data(people)
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; })
    .attr("d", d3.svg.symbol()
    .size(function(d) { return d.size; })
    .type(function(d) { return d.type; }))
    .style("fill", p.color)
    .attr("class","person")
    .attr("id","p_"+index)

    index++;

}
```

Comment: ...and this doesn't work? It looks like your selector should be `d3.select(el + " > svg")`.

Comment: No it does not work. It almost works. It renders all the circles in correct SVG. but it only animates one of the svgs. (tbhe first one)

Comment: Try `var svg =` instead of `svg =` at the beginning of the `drawSvg` function.

Comment: unfortunately that does not help in this case.

Comment: Could you provide a complete example please?